# Как изменить по событию hover , path в svg?

Tags: svg, hover

Собственно сам вопрос в заголовке

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg8" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 297 210">
<g transform="translate(0,-87)">
    <g transform="translate(96.005953,-11.717262)">
      <path style="fill:#ff0000;"
         d="m 88.068448,145.05357 0.412385,-29.44046 25.702377,-14.3631 25.29,15.07737 -0.41239,29.44046 -25.70238,14.3631 z"
         transform="matrix(1.9453451,0,0,1.6983429,-87.970972,-61.598729)" />
      <path  style="opacity:1;fill:#501616;"
         d="m 85.620408,182.81115 0.753717,-46.40922 46.976195,-22.64163 46.22247,23.76759 -0.75372,46.40922 -46.97619,22.64164 z" />
    </g>
  
  
    <path
       transform="matrix(1.9453451,0,0,1.6983429,-143.08245,-78.415574)"
       d="m 88.068448,145.05357 0.412385,-29.44046 25.702377,-14.3631 25.29,15.07737 -0.41239,29.44046 -25.70238,14.3631 z"  style="fill:#ff0000;" />
    <path d="m 30.508928,165.99431 0.375741,-9.36755 47.354171,0.0369 46.22247,-1.17883 -0.75372,11.63541 -46.97619,22.64164 z"  style="fill:#501616;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Имеется такой `hexagon` а svg и в соответствии с макетом на нём должен произойти `hover` и по этому событию должно произойти увеличение тёмного элемента, я всё сделал за исключением `hover`.

Как мне раньше объясняли что должно быть одинаковое ко-во точек и именно это условие я предусмотрел ..

Как в этом случае сделать так что бы было как во втором `hexagon` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
#pouring {
  transition: 1s;
}

#hexagon:hover #pouring {
 d: path("m 85.620408,182.81115 0.753717,-46.40922 46.976195,-22.64163 46.22247,23.76759 -0.75372,46.40922 -46.97619,22.64164 z");
 d: "m 85.620408,182.81115 0.753717,-46.40922 46.976195,-22.64163 46.22247,23.76759 -0.75372,46.40922 -46.97619,22.64164 z";
 transform: translate(-55px, -17px);
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg8" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 297 210" >
  <g transform="translate(0,-87)" id="hexagon">
    <path transform="matrix(1.9453451,0,0,1.6983429,-143.08245,-78.415574)" d="m 88.068448,145.05357 0.412385,-29.44046 25.702377,-14.3631 25.29,15.07737 -0.41239,29.44046 -25.70238,14.3631 z" style="fill:#ff0000;" />
    <path id="pouring" d="m 30.508928,165.99431 0.375741,-9.36755 47.354171,0.0369 46.22247,-1.17883 -0.75372,11.63541 -46.97619,22.64164 z"  style="fill:#501616;" />
  </g>
</svg>
```